# Is there any fix to the login redirect bug with React?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, reactjs, web

I'm getting perplexed with this, because I've pasted the entire code from their documentation (auth0) and it seems not to be working and I don't know why but I keep getting that error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loginWithRedirect' of undefined
```

on their original wrapper here

```
 loginWithRedirect: (...p) => auth0Client.loginWithRedirect(...p),
```

and pointed to my NavMenu.js file on this line

```
<button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Login</button>
```

Here's the entire code of implementation Auth0 to my NavMenu

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Container, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarToggler, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavMenu.css';

import {useAuth0} from '../auth0-wrapper';


const NavMenu = () => {
  const {isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout, loading} = useAuth0 ();
  return (
    <header>
      <Navbar className="navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm ng-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3" light>
        <Container>
          <NavbarBrand tag={Link} to="/">Hotel</NavbarBrand>
          {isAuthenticated ? (
            <ul className="navbar-nav flex-grow">
            <NavItem>
                <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/create">Create</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink tag={Link} className="text-dark" to="/bookings">Bookings</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => logout()}>Log out</button>
              </NavItem>
            </ul>
          ) : (
            <ul lassName="navbar-nav flex-grow">
             <NavItem>
                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Login</button>
              </NavItem>
            </ul>
          )}
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </header>
  );

}

export default NavMenu;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `auth0Client` is probably not imported successfully.

Comment: @AlexandreLage I reinstalled ```auth0Client``` 3 times and still not working

Comment: How are you installing it? Please, show a little bit more of your situation. @cssnoobie

Comment: @AlexandreLage I'm installing it by using their documentation and the command in node js ```npm install @auth0/auth0-spa-js --save```

Comment: Alright. You are using node indeed. And how are you importing `auth0Client` at the top of your code?

Comment: In fact, could you please edit your question with the implementation of `createAuth0Client `

Comment: @ofundefined I'm importing it by ```import {useAuth0} from '../auth0-wrapper';``` and yes I will edit it.

Comment: Alright. Could you please show us a little bit of your file `auth0-wrapper` where you use `createAuth0Client`. PLEASE do not post your credentials! haha

Answer (score 2):

I got this error as well. If you look in through the Chrome Dev tools you might see you are getting a 400 error while loading resources from auth0. Here is the error: [400 Error by auth0 Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vC0m.png)

If this is the case your problem is most likely a misconfiguration of Allowed Origins on the auth0 application settings. Any error here will cause this problem. I was had the same problem, solved it, and was able to replicate the issue for this answer.

For development I was using `http://localhost:3000/` but the `/` at the end was causing the resources not to load. Try to go over your settings in auth0 and make sure that your Allowed urls and origins are correct.

Comment: This solved it for me! Just updated the Application URIs all to http://localhost:3000 and it's working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs even if you use the demo code exactly as posted.
The strange thing is that it works occasionally.

I found a *"half fix"*:

```
// in App.js  

const { loading, user, isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0();

if (loading) {
  return <Loading />;
}

return (<></>);
```

This only converts the error into a forever loading screen. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Actually, that seems to work.  I added that fix and the spinner took a solid 1-2 minutes but then worked.  Thereafter, it worked normally.  I think something is in a wierd state and had to time out/reset then work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this bug recently when building a React app with Auth-0. I had not implemented the `<PrivateRoute/>` functionality yet but kept getting the error. If you go and delete the Auth-0 token from cookies within your browser, this error will go away until the `<PrivateRoute/>` component is implemented.